# How to record local and remote stream in a webrtc video conference?

Tags: webrtc

I have made a wbertc one to one video chat. The local stream is loading in a video element with id localvid and remote stream is loading in another video element id remotevid

i can access local audio, video stream using

window.localStream.getVideoTracks()
 window.localStream.getAudioTracks()

How i can save the local and remote stream in my www localtion server where the solution running?

Comment: This could be helpful
https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/ You can try check src code of this example https://www.WebRTC-Experiment.com/RecordRTC.js One comment from this sample: > The biggest issue is that RecordRTC is unable to record both audio and
> video streams in single file.

Comment: i know this muaz khan stuff. but it is not much bug free and issue with browser support. any other source?

Comment: I think there is no right now any super bug free and easy solution. Good way - use this and other similar open source examples and build own solution in your context. Unfortunately WebRTC is too young now :(

Comment: @newdeveloper "this muaz khan stuff" :D :D :P
Did you find the solution of your question. Please share